# Compare two List<T> using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have two list of Medecine Objects:

```
List<Medecine> list1;
List<Medecine> list2;
```

`MedecineID`, `MedecineName` etc are properties of `Medecine`; `MedecineID is unique.

I want a list objects that are in `list1` but not in `list2`;

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = list1.Except(list2);
var list1NotList2 = query.ToList();
```

This will give you all the items that are in `list1` but not `list2`.

Note that you would need to ensure that your `Medecine` objects can be compared for equality properly (usually via `Equals`/`GetHashCode`). You can also pass in a custom `IEqualityComparer` as the final argument to `Except`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) for more information on `Except`.

Answer (score 2):

The natural way to do this in LINQ is by using the [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) method:

```
var results = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

However, for this to work you have to tell LINQ when two objects are "the same". You can do this by having `Medecine` implement `IEquatable<Medecine>` like this:

```
class Medecine : IEquatable<Medecine>
{
    public int MedecineID { get; set; }
    public string MedecineName { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
         return this.MedecineID;
    }

    public bool Equals(Medecine other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) {
            return true;
        }
        return other.MedecineID == this.MedecineID;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Medecine)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((Medecine)obj);
    }
}
```

If this approach is not suitable, you can make an `IEqualityComparer<Medecine>` and pass that to `Except` as an additional parameter:

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Medecine>
{
    public bool Equals(Medecine x, Medecine y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return x.MedecineID == y.MedecineID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Medecine obj)
    {
        return obj.MedecineID;
    }
}

var results = list1.Except(list2, new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid writing a custom comparison object for your medicine class, then you could just project the "MedecineId" out of the second list into a new collection, then use [IEnumerable.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) to create your "desired" list:

```
class Medecine
{
    public Guid MedecineId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    // whatever other fields
}
```

Create some test data:

```
List<Guid> mIds = 
    new List<Guid>( Enumerable.Range( 0, 20 ).Select( n => Guid.NewGuid() ) );

List<Medecine> m1 = new List<Medecine>
(
    Enumerable.Range( 0, 10 ).Select( c => new Medecine() { MedecineId = mIds.ElementAt( c ), Name = c.ToString() } )
);

List<Medecine> m2 = new List<Medecine>
(
    Enumerable.Range( 5, 15 ).Select( d => new Medecine() { MedecineId = mIds.ElementAt( d ), Name = d.ToString() } )
);
```

Then getting your results is simply:

```
var excludedIds = m2.Select( m2s => m2s.MedecineId).Distinct();
var results = m1.Where( m1s => !excludedIds.Contains( m1s.MedecineId ));
```